# HI, New to programming with textfiles loops and much more

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, stream, streamreader

i have a textfile which is in this format

[image]

and i am trying to use a stream reader to help me loop each word into a text box, i am new to programming and really need help because all other examples are too complicated for me to understand,

this is what i am trying to do :

```
Dim objectreader As New StreamReader("filepath")
    Dim linereader(1) As String


    linereader = Split(objectreader.ReadLine, ",")
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(linereader)
        Spelling_Test.txtSpelling1.Text = linereader(0)
        Spelling_Test.txtSpelling2.Text = linereader(0)  
    Next
```

but only get the first line of the text file in to a textbox, i need it to loop to the next line so i can write the next line in!

your help would be much appreciated, and if possible then can you show it practically , if you dont understand what i am trying to do then please ask

Comment: you need an outer loop to process file lines as well as the inner one to parse each line - your code is only reading on line from the file

Comment: build up a string and then set the tesxtbox = thestring
myString = myString & linereader(i).   linereader(0) is only the first element in the array

Comment: can you show a practical example please thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little confusing on what you are trying to do, it looks like your text file consists of a word and a hint, you only have one set of textbox's and 3 lines of information in your file.

This example show you how to incrementally read your Stream.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim objectreader As StreamReader
    Dim linereader() As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If IsNothing(objectreader) Then
            objectreader = New StreamReader("C:\Temp\data.txt")
        End If

        linereader = Split(objectreader.ReadLine, ",")
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(linereader(0)) Then
            objectreader.Close()
            objectreader = Nothing
        Else
            txtSpelling1.Text = linereader(0) 'Word
            txtSpelling2.Text = linereader(1)  'Hint
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

But in your case, I would probably just use the [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim result As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\data.txt")
    For x = 0 To UBound(result)
        Dim c As Control = Controls.Find("txtSpelling" + (x + 1).ToString, True)(0)
        If Not IsNothing(c) Then
            c.Text = Split(result(x), ",")(0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the program is a spelling bee, and it needs to display the spellings and defintions in the textboxes, i am really new to programming and have been trying to sort this one out for a long time, but nothing is clicking. the spelling goes in to txtspelling and the definition would go into txtdefintion (not in the code) the problem comes when trying to get the second line into to txtspelling to and so on, and thankyou for you reply